# Menu button press not identified in MapActivity

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout

I have a mapactivity and I'm not able to override the onPrepareOptionsMenu from that activity. How to solve this?

Comment: it is because the activity is being paused at the moment and so the onPrepareOptionsMenu is not called.. I dont knw the reason ... may b u shud call the onResume fn ... i havent tried

Answer (score 0):

onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu); when calling the implementation in the Activity class